# Как подключить jar, созданный на clojure к проекту Android studio на Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, clojure

Задача - подключить .jar созданный lein'ом в clojure к проекту Android studio на java. jar, созданный в clojure содержит класс, функции которого нужно использовать в java коде в Android приложении. Попробовал сперва на компе для обычного java проекта по инструкции отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181774/calling-clojure-from-java
Все получилось. Далее подключил модули clojure-1.6 и моей библиотеки на clojure к Android studio проекту. Все подключилось, даже функции видит. Устанавливаться на устройство не захотел, ладно заменил clojure-1.6 на clojure-1.6slim, все, установился. Но приложение при запуске просто вылетает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

1)

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at clojure.lang.Namespace.

2)

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file, compiling:(clojure/core.clj:29:7)

3)

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет при вылете?